# CSS not working for span tag hover, which is inside button tag in Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: css

CSS not working for span tag hover, which is inside button tag in Firefox and Internet Explorer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
span:hover{
  color:red;
}
</style>
<body>
<button type="button">Click Me!<span>Hello world</span></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try button:hover span ?

Comment: IE 10 and also in firefox.

Comment: In firefox this is work for me : https://jsfiddle.net/AnTSaSk/uu4t5bk7/ (i have Edge and its works too)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it also work for me.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is easily reproduced and not a typo. (Also, the solution below doesn't quite give the same behavior as the css above implies to be intended.) If you disagree, please do explain in which way this question is off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try like this

```css
button:hover span{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Me!<span>Hello world</span></button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This code was not working.
span:hover{
  color:red;
}